# WPF C# Download Multiple Files

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't seem to find any examples of downloading multiple files from a URL.
I have a URL lets say www.example.com/Document and I want to download all the files in that URL is that possible? or do I need to provide the name of each file in that URL? All the files would download to a folder specified here in the code.

Any examples of this would be great, this would be done by clicking a Download button in WPF.

Comment: How can you download multiple files from an URL? Even using a browser, 1 url is 1 file

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to create a ZIP file and have all the files in there. You can either pre create a ZIP file and download or you can create the ZIP file as it downloads. I had to write my own software to do that but it does work.